# How do I turn 6 lg colums into 3 md columns without exceeding 12 in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, arrays, twitter-bootstrap

I have several rows such as the the one below displaying 6 columns. Each column contains a linked image. The images/links are working fine - with a reasonable screen width the columns display as they should do. But when the screen width gets smaller all the images stack on top of each other. I need a way of setting it so when the screen width gets smaller i can set it to 3 columns instead of 6. Since Bootstrap doesn't support more than 12 columns in a row i can't put col-md-4 in each column. Are there any solutions here that doesn't involve reconstructing all of the rows because as you can see it would be very tricky because each row echos a specific array item.

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-2">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[0]. '"> <img src=".$thing[0].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[1]. '"> <img src=".$thing[1].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[2]. '"> <img src=".$thing[2].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[3]. '"> <img src=".$thing[3].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[4]. '"> <img src=".$thing[4].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[5]. '"> <img src=".$thing[5].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div> </div>
```

Is this what you mean?I have made the following changes and it doesn't work

```
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[0]. '"> <img src=".$thing[0].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[1]. '"> <img src=".$thing[1].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[2]. '"> <img src=".$thing[2].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
        <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[3]. '"> <img src=".$thing[3].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[4]. '"> <img src=".$thing[4].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
        <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[5]. '"> <img src=".$thing[5].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
        </div></div>
```

Comment: Just add the class `col-md-4` and wrap every 3 divs a `row` dynamically

Comment: @bob - *...i can't put `col-md-4` in each column*. Why not. Sure you can. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6sj1ddk9/)

Answer (score 1):

just change add an addclass with the html

html

```
<div class="col-lg-6 col-md-3">
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap does allow more than 12 columns per row, however you have to clearfix them. Here's how you do it:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[0]. '"> <img src=".$thing[0].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[1]. '"> <img src=".$thing[1].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[2]. '"> <img src=".$thing[2].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
    <div class="clearfix hidden-lg"></div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[3]. '"> <img src=".$thing[3].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[4]. '"> <img src=".$thing[4].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4">  <?php echo '<p> <a '.$thing[5]. '"> <img src=".$thing[5].'_" /></a></p>'; ?> </div> 
</div>
```

The clearfix div creates a separation between the columns, acting as if the columns were split in two rows. Except the clearfix class is hidden on large screens by the `hidden-lg` class causing the columns to stack nicely into six columns on large screens, while on medium screens and lower the columns break up in two rows of 3 columns.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate that.